# (Ruby) regex optional matches

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm writing a Rack app to split hostnames ending with certain prefixes.

For example, the hostname (and port) `hello.world.lvh.me:3000` needs to be split into tokens `hello.world`, `.lvh.me` and `:3000`. Additionally, the prefix (`hello.world`), suffix (`.lvh.me`) and port (`:3000`) are all optional.

So far, I have a (Ruby) regex that looks like `/(.*)(\.lvh\.me)(\:\d+)?/`.

This successfully breaks the hostname into component parts but it falls down when one or more of the optional components is missing, e.g. for `hello.world:3000` or `lvh.me:3000` or even plain old `hello.world`.

I've tried adding `?` to each group to make them optional (`/(.*)?(\.lvh\.me)?(\:(\d+)?/`) but this invariably ends up with the first group, `(.*)`, capturing the entire string and stopping there.

My gut feeling is that this is something which might be solved using lookaround but I'll admit this is a totally new realm of regex for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `^(.*?)?(\.?lvh\.me)?(\:\d+)?$`

I added:

- a `?` to the first group making the `*` non-greedy
- `^,$` to anchor it to the start and end.
- a `?` to the `\.` before `lvh` because you want to match `lvh.me:3000` not `.lvh.me:3000`

Comment: Even though @casimir's answer is more robust, I've accepted this answer as it's adequate enough for my purposes and is what I've ended up using. Basically, I don't need the regex to care if any group is missing, just that each group matches what it's designed to and nothing else.

Comment: Are you certain that you want `^` and `$` rather than `\A` and `\z`? Probably won't make any difference in this case but good habits are good habits.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this pattern:

```
\A(?=[^:])(.+?)??((?:\.|\A)lvh\.me)?(:[0-9]+)?\z
```

the lookahead `(?=[^:])` checks there is at least one character that is not the `:` *(in other words, not the port alone)*. This means that at least `hello.word` or `lvh.me` is present.

The first group is optional and non-greedy `??`, this means that it is matched only when needed.

`\A` and `\z` are anchors for the start and the end of the string *(when `^` and `$` are used for the line)*

Note that the character class `\d` matches all unicode digits in Ruby, but in this case you only need ascii digits. It's better to use `[0-9]`

Note too that `\A(?=[^:])((?>[^l:\n.]+|\.|\Bl|l(?!vh\.me\b))*)((?:\.|\A)lvh\.me)?(:[0-9]+)?\z` may be more performant.

[online demo](http://rubular.com/r/0VIYqD2cs1)

Comment: Almost there but with `lvh.me:3000`, `lvh.me` is captured by the first group rather than its own group.

Comment: Love it! I've learned some new things today from your answer.

Comment: A reminder about `\A` and `\z` versus `^` and `$` might be useful, that's a very common point of confusion with Ruby's regexes.

Answer (score 2):

### A Tokenizing Answer

Just for fun, I decided to see if there was a relatively simple way to do what you wanted without a complicated regular expression. The only regular expressions I used were for splitting and validation.

This works for me with your provided corpus, and several variations.

```
str    = 'hello.world.lvh.me:3000'
tokens = str.split /[.:]/
port   = tokens.last =~ /\A\d+\z/ ? ?: + tokens.pop : ''
domain = sprintf '.%s.%s', *tokens.pop(2)
prefix = tokens.join ?.
```

You'll certainly need to check for empty strings in certain cases, but it seems like it might be more straightforward and/or flexible than a pure regex solution. *I* find it more readable, anyway. If you truly need a single regular expression, though, I'm sure one of the other answers will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting rather than matching,

```
irb(main):012:0> "hello.world.lvh.me:3000".split(/\.(?=[^.:]+\.[^:.]+(?::\d+)?$)|:/)
=> ["hello.world", "lvh.me", "3000"]
irb(main):013:0> "hello.world:3000".split(/\.(?=[^.:]+\.[^:.]+(?::\d+)?$)|:/)
=> ["hello.world", "3000"]
irb(main):014:0> "lvh.me:3000".split(/\.(?=[^.:]+\.[^:.]+(?::\d+)?$)|:/)
=> ["lvh.me", "3000"]
irb(main):015:0> "hello.world".split(/\.(?=[^.:]+\.[^:.]+(?::\d+)?$)|:/)
=> ["hello.world"]
irb(main):016:0> "hello.world.lvh.me".split(/\.(?=[^.:]+\.[^:.]+(?::\d+)?$)|:/)
=> ["hello.world", "lvh.me"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, ma, no regex!

```
def split_up(str)
  str.sub(':','.:')
     .split('.')
     .each_slice(2)
     .map { |arr| arr.join('.') }
end

split_up("hello.world.lvh.me:3000") #=> ["hello.world", "lvh.me", ":3000"]
split_up("hello.world:3000")        #=> ["hello.world", ":3000"]
split_up("hello.world.lvh.me")      #=> ["hello.world", "lvh.me"]
split_up("hello.world")             #=> ["hello.world"]
split_up("")                        #=> []
```

Steps:

```
str1 = "hello.world.lvh.me:3000" #=> "hello.world.lvh.me:3000"
str2 = str1.sub(':','.:')        #=> "hello.world.lvh.me.:3000"
arr  = str2.split('.')           #=> ["hello", "world", "lvh", "me", ":3000"]
enum = arr.each_slice(2)         #=> #<Enumerator: ["hello", "world", "lvh",
                                 #     "me", ":3000"]:each_slice(2)>
enum.to_a                        #=> [["hello", "world"], ["lvh", "me"],
                                 #    [":3000"]]
enum.map { |arr| arr.join('.') } #=> ["hello.world", "lvh.me", ":3000"]
```